# Binding to a set of values

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Let's say that I have a textbox like below. I'd like to bind it to a set of values that I would set programtically in the viewmodel.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Address" Style="{StaticResource tabTextBlock}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding test.test2}" Style="{StaticResource tabTextBox}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

So the ViewModel would look something like...

```
public class test
{
    string test2 = "TEST";
}
```

how would the syntax for this look in the viewmodel? I know that for a single value the code would look something like

```
public string Test
{
    get { return _Test; }
    set { _Test = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Test)); }
}
private string _Test = "";
```

I'm just not sure how to expand this to include a local variables under Test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the binding path `test.test2`, `test` refers to a property of the `DataContext` (view model) of the `TextBox` and `test2` refers to a property of this view model.

So if you set the `DataContext` of the `StackPanel` (or any of its parent elements) to the following class:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public Test test { get; } => new Test();
}
```

...and define the `Test` class something like this:

```
public class Test : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string test2
    {
        get { return _test2; }
        set { _test2 = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(test2)); }
    }
    ...
}
```

...the binding will work.

Of course you could add as many properties as you like to the `Test` class and bind to these the same way.